# C# visual studio using Ni Visa

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to add NI visa 2022 Q3 in my visual studio 2019 target framework is .Net framework 4.7.2,I tried the tutorial on National Instruments, but it seems outdated.

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xsJAXnNvnm8&t=209s

I follow the tutorial on youtube tried to add Visacomlib, When I add Visacomlib in my reference visual studio show the warning sign which means I am using the wrong framework, but the document says it need to be .Net 4.0 or later. I tried diffrent framework version too (the version I tried is 4 , 4.5 , 4.5.1 , 4.6 , 4.6.1 , 4.7.2 , 4.8) what have I done wrong I can't call the function or use it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the build output, and change the verbosity in Visual Studio's settings if necessary to get more detailed info.

Comment: There ought to be some kind of warning or info in the Output window to help you.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the error message is""ResolveComReference" job returned False, but no error was logged", I am not english user so I use google translate.